# Yii2 - Render view located in subfolder

Tags: php, view, yii2, render, subdirectory

I'm working with Yii2 and I wonder which is the right way to render from a controller a file located within a subfolder in views directory. For example, I have the following situation:

```
views
-campus (carpeta)
--actividad (subcarpeta)
---2020.php (vista)
```

So far, I've tried this options but without success:

```
return $this->render('/actividad/2020',[]); 
return $this->render('/actividad/2020',[],$this->context); 
return $this->render('2020',[],$this->context); 
return $this->render('@app/views/campus/actividad/2020',[]); 
return $this->render('//actividad/2020',[]);
```

My controller `CampusController`:

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;
class CampusController extends \yii\web\Controller
{  
    public function action2020()
    {
        return $this->render('actividad/2020');
        //return $this->render('/campus/actividad/2020');
        //return $this->render('//campus/actividad/2020');
        //return $this->render('@app/views/campus/actividad/2020');
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `return $this->render('actividad/2020',[])`.

Comment: I also tried @rob006

Comment: Could you try `return $this->render('@frontend/views/campus/actividad/2020');`  ?

Comment: I did already. The same, page not found!

Comment: @4aLifeTime If you have "page not found" error, it means that framework is unable to find your **action**, so code for view rendering is never executed. You should focus on trying to call your action first. You could try with simple `return 'test';` instead of view rendering, and check if works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on `CampusController`, want to render `2020.php`, and have the folder structure that you show in your question:

```
views
-campus (carpeta)
--actividad (subcarpeta)
---2020.php (vista)
```

All the following ways would work:

```
return $this->render('actividad/2020');
return $this->render('/campus/actividad/2020');
return $this->render('//campus/actividad/2020');
return $this->render('@app/views/campus/actividad/2020');
```

If you are not passing any parameters to the view, you can pass an empty array, but you can also remove the second parameter.

You do **need to return the result of `$this->render(...)`**, in your question it looks like you are calling return **after**, that would return an empty response instead of the result of rendering the view file.

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo. I couldnt access, it says "page not found". I will edit my question with my controller code.